# How get id and class in Angular 4.x

Tags: angular

HTML code, here am using class inside 
  the [ngClass] and also *ngIf Condition is also using in every html tag

```
<span class="damageNavigator ">
     <span id="tab1" [ngClass]="countInterior !== 0 ? 'damage-tab-section-active' : ''"
           (click)="swiperCallTab(indexInterior,1)"
           *ngIf="countInterior !== 0">Interior</span>
</span>

<span class="damageNavigator">
 <span id="tab2" [ngClass]="countInterior == 0 && countExterior !== 0 ? 
  'damage-tab-section-active' : ''"
       *ngIf="countExterior !== 0"
       (click)="swiperCallTab(indexExterior,2)">Exterior</span>
</span>

<span class="damageNavigator">
  <span id="tab3" [ngClass]="countInterior == 0 && countExterior == 0 &&
   countOther !== 0 ? 'damage-tab-section-active' : ''"
        *ngIf="countOther !== 0"
        (click)="swiperCallTab(indexOther,3)">Others</span>
</span>
```

> My .ts File Code 
>       Instead of using document.getElementById And 
>         document.getElementByClassName  i need Angular refence to complete this code

```
  document.getElementsByClassName('damage-tab-section-active')
  [0].classList.remove('damage-tab-section-active');
        document.getElementById('tab' + flag).classList.add('damage-tab-
     section-active');
```

Comment: What problem will the alternate DOM selector method solve ?

Comment: Its not the right way to use Javascript references in angular code.. i need to change to Angular references

Comment: Do you need these on any particular case like on click event? Or does it require on initialization of the component?

Comment: "@angular/core": "^4.3.6",

Comment: Its Required .. currently am using javascript  reference document.getelementById.. its working fine .. iam used this inside a swiper plugin for changing the tab when image is slide.. but they not need JavaScript reference .. so iam trying to change to Angular reference.. Here @ViewChild And nativeElement is not working

Comment: Have you tried with @ViewChild.

Comment: Btw there are way better/easier ways to set the classes to these elements using the [Angular Class Bindings](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax). And can you send errors/logs of the `@ViewChild` failing... bcs thats wierd I never had problems with ViewChild, ElementRef and NativeElements

Answer (score 0):

You could try with **@ViewChild**

Html

```
<span #myspan >Stackoverflow</span>

<button (click)="onclick()">Invoke</button>
```

Component.ts

```
import {Component, NgModule, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'

@ViewChild('myspan') public myspan: any;  

onclick() {
 console.log(this.myspan);
}
```

[Working plunker sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/F5SVEUBO2LJngz1epc9j?p=preview)